# Current flows without any potential difference

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

why current if flowing if there is no potential difference. if no potential difference then no work is being done on charge so there should be no net displacement of charge but we know that the current flows. current also flows from higher potential to lower potential but across two ends potential is same(potential difference zero) so no current should flow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Potential difference across a zero resistance wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409310/)

Comment: This is a re-post of the question you posted just yesterday. It is still a duplicate of the old questions we cited in comments. Please refer to the answers to those old questions.

Comment: Your post from yesterday: [Potential difference across a wire](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555332/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can charge flow between two points if their potential difference is 0?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299079/)

Comment: Rans Some, I've downvoted your question for the "does not show any research effort" reason. You might find the following link helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - *"Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential difference $V$ between two points is the work required per unit charge to move the charge between two points. If current is flowing between two points with no potential difference it means there is no resistance between the points requiring work to overcome. This is the assumption we make when we treat wires in an electrical circuit as having zero resistance. Current flows in the wires between circuit components without a potential difference between points in the wire.

In reality all conductors, except super cooled conductors, have resistance. We just assume the resistance of wires is so low compared to the resistance of the components they connect that we can ignore it.

A mechanical analog is an object (analogous to electric charge) sliding at constant velocity (analogous to constant velocity) on a frictionless surface (analogous to a conductor with zero resistance). Since there is no friction to overcome, no work is required to move the object over the surface and the object can go on forever at constant speed  without any work. In reality, of course,  there is no such thing as a truly frictionless surface and the object will eventually come to a stop unless an external force is applied to equal the friction force and keep the object going.

Hope this helps.