# Concept of short circuits

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, short-circuits

Starting from my secondary school, I have never understood the concept of short circuits. For instance, why would current prefer a path with no resistance than a path with much resistance? How does it know or decide that that there is much resistance in the one path and no resistance in the other? I know I am imagining current as a person that has his own will. But what is the physics behind it? None of my teachers were able to give me a satisfying answer so far and it really bugs me.

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33621 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5670 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74368 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69919 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7936 etc.

Comment: oh okay. Could not find duplicates before posting. I will delete

Comment: Because the conservation of energy says there's no reason to give up energy traversing the higher resistance path if you don't have to.